# how to update cart quantity in CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter, sql-update, updates, shopping-cart, cart

I want to update the quantity of a shopping cart. I've google it a lot but couldn't do it.

Maximum pages are showing which i don't want. Exactly solution i'm not getting. Hopefully i will get here. Please help me to do it. Here is my **view page**.

```
**<table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped snipcart-details ">    <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th style="color:#FF0033; font-weight:bolder; text-align:center;" >Delete Cart</th>
                  <th style="color:#FF0033; font-weight:bolder; text-align:center;" >Product Name</th>
                  <th style="color:#FF0033; font-weight:bolder; text-align:center;" >Image</th>
                  <th style="color:#FF0033; font-weight:bolder; text-align:center;" >Price</th>
                  <th style="color:#FF0033; font-weight:bolder; text-align:center;" >Quantity</th>                    
                  <th colspan="2" style="color:#FF0033; font-weight:bolder; text-align:center;" >Total</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>                 
              <?php  foreach ($this->cart->contents() as $items) { ?> 
                <tr>                      
                  <td style="color:#000000; font-weight:bolder; text-align:center;" >
                    <a href="#" class="remove_cart" title="delete" row_id="<?php echo $items['rowid']; ?>" rel="1">
                    <i class="fa fa-times fa-2x" style="color:red;" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a></td>
                  <td style="color:#000000; font-weight:bolder; text-align:center;" ><?php echo $items['name']; ?></td>
                  <td   align="center"><img src="<?php echo base_url('resource/allproduct/'.$items['productImage']);?>" height="50px;" /></td></td>
                  <td  style="color:#000000; font-weight:bolder; text-align:center;"><?php echo $items['price']; ?></td>
                  <td  align="center"><input type="number" name="qty" id="qty" value="<?php echo $items['qty']; ?>"></td>               
            <td colspan="2"  style="color:#000000; font-weight:bolder; text-align:center;">TK <?php echo $this->cart->format_number($items['subtotal']); ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php } ?>
             </tbody>                
             <tbody>
                <tr>                     
                   <th scope="row"><a href="">  <input type="button" name="submit" value="Update" class="button" /> </a></th>
                  <td  align="center"><a href="<?php echo site_url('home'); ?>"> <input type="button" name="submit" value="Continue Shopping" class="button" /></a></td>
                  <td colspan="3" class="button" align="center" >       
                                  <?php if(!empty($userid)){?> 
                                   <a href="<?php echo site_url("checkout"); ?>"><input class="button" type="submit" value="Place Order"></a>
                                  <?php } else {?> 
                                    <a href="<?php echo site_url("login"); ?>"><input class="button" type="submit" value="Place Order"></a>                                     
                                  <?php }?>                                                     
                  </td>
                  <td  align="center" style="color:#000000;" > <h4>Grand Total</h4> </td>
                  <td style="font-size:24px; font-weight:800; color:green;">TK <?php echo $this->cart->format_number($this->cart->total()); ?></td>         
              </tr>
             </tbody>
        </table>**
```

And here is **controler**.

```
    public function index()
{   
    $data['basicinfo']          = $this->M_cloud->basicall('basic_info');
    $where                      = array('status' => 1);
    $data['categoryinfo']       = $this->M_cloud->categoryinfo('item_manage', $where);
    $data['rows']               = count($this->cart->contents());       
    $data['userid']             = $this->session->userdata('user_id');      
    $data['subcategoryinfo']  = $this->M_cloud->findAll2('sub_category', array('status' => 1));     
    $data['menuinformation']    = $this->M_cloud->findReport('our_service', array('serviceType'=> 2), 'menuname asc');
    $data['menuservice']        = $this->M_cloud->findReport('our_service', array('serviceType'=> 1), 'menuname asc');      
    $data['socialmedia']        = $this->M_cloud->findAll('social_tbl', 'name asc');
    $data['newsinfo']           = $this->M_cloud->findAll('news_table', 'newstitle DESC');  
    $this->load->view('cartPage', $data);       
}

    public function buy()
{   
    $proId = $this->input->post('proId');
    $Qty   = $this->input->post('Qty');
    $prosize = $this->input->post('prosize');       
    $result = $this->M_cloud->find('product_manage', array('proid' => $proId));     
    $data2 = array(
                'id'                    => $proId,
                'qty'                   => $Qty,
                'name'                  => $result->proName,
                'price'                 => $result->price,
                'prosize'               => $prosize,
                'productImage'          => $result->proimg1,
                'product_code'          => $result->procode                 
            );  
    $this->cart->insert($data2);        
    redirect('cart');   
}

public function deleteCartItem() {
    $row_id              = $this->input->post('row_id');
    $data = array(
        'rowid'   => $row_id,
        'qty'     => 0
    );
    $this->cart->update($data);
}
```

Please help me how to update cart quantity. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

To update cart Item :

```
function updateCartItem(){
      $data=array(
             'rowid'=>$this->input->post('rowid',TRUE),
             'qty'=> $this->input->post('quantity',TRUE)
              );

                if ($this->cart->update($data)) {
                 echo "Success";         
                }else{
                     echo "Faliure";
                }

}
```

To remove the item from cart :

```
function deleteCartItem(){
$row_id = $this->input->post('row_id',TRUE);
  if ($rowid) {
            return $this->cart->remove($rowid);
        }
}
```

Comment: Where is the view page action?

Comment: i can help you with errors not with functionality you have to design your own cart page

Comment: I mean to  say how to call in action the control?? <?php echo site_url('controler_name/funcntion_name');?> that's it only or somthing else way i should call???? Please let me know

Comment: May be you can your `ajax POST` Method